# CMake remove_directory command don't work when run by execute_process

Tags: cmake

I have some archive that I want to unpack at generation step. Before doing so I want to remove the directories if they have already been unpacked. For this I use `cmake -E remove_directory ${DIR}` (which work when used from the command line) but when the directory is present and the command is ran from execute_process in the cmakelists it doesn't work for no apparent reason

The error I get:

```
Error removing directory
"/path/to/directory".
```

The execute_process part:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} "-E" "remove_directory" ${DIR}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PATH})
```

Comment: More info, please. Operating System, **exact** values of `PATH` and `DIR` variables, what is specific in the directory's content (that is, have you tried this with existed but empty directory).

Comment: Describe better when it works and when not.

Comment: The equivalent command should be `file(REMOVE_RECURSE [<files>...])` since this is already being run in the context of a CMake script.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did what I wanted with `file`.